# Apply Directive to specific Div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, vlc

**Ctrl**

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#divStreamingAreaPlayback' + pictureboxIndex)).append($compile("<vlc-object name= 'fname'></vlc-object>")($scope));
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="cameraControls"></div>
```

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive('vlcObject', function ($compile, $rootScope,$timeout) {
var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var vlcPlayerTemplate =

            '<object id="vlc'+'{{name}}" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" width="100%" height="100%">' +
            '<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" name="vlc'+'{{name}}" autoplay="yes" toolbar="false" width="100%" height="100%" target="' + $rootScope.rtspUrl + '"></embed>' +
            '</object>';
        element.html(vlcPlayerTemplate);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope); 
    });

};
return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: { name: '='},
    replace: true,
    link: linker


};
```

});

**When first div is selected we are passing id 01 and below is the output**

```
<vlc-object name="fname" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
<object width="100%" height="100%" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" id="vlcdivPictureBoxPlayback01" class="ng-scope">
<embed width="100%" height="100%" target="rtsp://media.smart-streaming.com/mytest/mp4:sample.mp4" toolbar="false" autoplay="yes" name="vlcdivPictureBoxPlayback01" type="application/x-vlc-plugin"></object></vlc-object>
```

**When second div is selected, first div id gets replaced by second div id as shown below**

```
<vlc-object name="fname" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
<object width="100%" height="100%" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" id="vlcdivPictureBoxPlayback02" class="ng-scope">
<embed width="100%" height="100%" target="rtsp://media.smart-streaming.com/mytest/mp4:sample.mp4" toolbar="false" autoplay="yes" name="vlcdivPictureBoxPlayback02" type="application/x-vlc-plugin"></object></vlc-object>

<vlc-object name="fname" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
<object width="100%" height="100%" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" id="vlcdivPictureBoxPlayback02" class="ng-scope">
<embed width="100%" height="100%" target="rtsp://media.smart-streaming.com/mytest/mp4:sample.mp4" toolbar="false" autoplay="yes" name="vlcdivPictureBoxPlayback02" type="application/x-vlc-plugin"></object></vlc-object>
```

As you can see the all div ids are replaced with last id. How do I apply directive to specific div and skip those who has already directive applied ?

Comment: You have `id` selector based DOM query, where `id="vlc'+'{{name}}"` will have same value..

Comment: @PankajParkar, I guess id is being used to maintain the uniqueness for vlc object. If vlc finds two same ids it will throw exception. What could be the alternate solution if not using id selector ?

Comment: @PankajParkar, I tried with name as well. But it seems its replacing with last id/name. How should one overcome such situation or any alternate solution ?

Comment: Could you create a plunkr or something?

Comment: @PankajParkar, could this be an issue of two way binding ? I just do not want to replace with last id's. Also directive called for one div should not be called for another.

Comment: Could it be the link() function called every time the element is to be bound to data in the $scope object ?